# Nested foreach not filling my dropdown correctly

Tags: php

I'm attempting to make 1 array out of 2 existing arrays (which cannot be modified). In order to do this I'm creating the array in a foreach which is nested in another foreach.

The code I used:

```
$language_option = array();
    foreach(Languages::getFullSelectOptionsList() as $country_description_1 => $country_code){
        foreach(Languages::getFullSelectOptionsList(TRUE) as $country_description_2 => $country_code){
            $language_option[$country_code] = $country_description_1.' - '.$country_description_2;
        }
    }
```

In this code "Languages::getFullSelectOptionsList()" returns an array with the 1st country descriptions.

And "Languages::getFullSelectOptionsList(TRUE)" returns an array with the 2nd country descriptions.

This is what my code does:
[dropdown results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqlff.png)

But what I'd like it to do is:
[dropdown wished results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpPib.png)

As you can see in the first picture only the last array value of "country_description_1" is used instead of using them all.

Are there any errors in my code, is this not possible to do or is there an easier way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to overwrite `$country_code` in your inner loop? Could that be an issue?

Comment: please show me the actual array which return `Languages::getFullSelectOptionsList()`

Comment: you need to use for loop, count your first array and make for loop upto that count, use index $i for those two array to get the data.
You are currently getting first country and then loop through all the country of second array, that's why you get that result. If you want me to do then comment

Comment: @KevinMGranger I did mean to overwrite that, yes.

Comment: @dinesh As requested: http://imgur.com/a/XIsSB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can get reference of this code.
But This will not work because you need to specify the values where `$first_array[$i]`

```
$language_option = array();
$first_array = Languages::getFullSelectOptionsList();
$second_array = Languages::getFullSelectOptionsList(TRUE);
for($i=0;$i<count($first_array); $i++){
    $language_option[$country_code] = $first_array[$i].' - '.$second_array[$i];
}
```

Instead of `$first_array[$i].' - '.$second_array[$i]` put code according to your array structure to get description or code (key value).

Comment: Thanks Shailesh! I'll try to work with this, I'm still quite new to programming in general.

Comment: Just see examples of looping through the array using for loop. In you case nested foreach will go `n*n` times but you need to loop through just `n` times.

Comment: watch out, `$country_code` will be undefined. maybe you can replace it with `key($first_array[$i])` or similar

Comment: @Cashbee Thanks for the tip, I just found out about it as well.